# Using Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am reading a paper by VAALER. He is using Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and saying that below function tends to $0$ as $N \to \infty$

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{\pi t}{\sin \pi t}(\cos \pi(2N+1)t)e^{2 \pi i t z} dt$$

Before this he has not written anything.
I am not able to understand why we can use that theorem. If you can give any hint.

Thanks

Comment: @Mattos Aren't you confusing $t\to\infty$ and $N\to \infty$ here? the $\cos(\pi(2N+1))$ is the part with the parameter going to $\infty$.

Comment: Could you please state the proposition or theorem you are using.If you can share a link please share . Thanks for help.

Comment: @HitendraKumar A relevant question here is: do you know the statement of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? If so, which of the assumptions is unclear to you here?

Comment: I know which says fourier coefficient goes to $0$ an N goes to infinity.

Comment: @HitendraKumar I cannot really parse what you just wrote. The R-L gives a conclusion (the limit of the integral is zero) under some assumptions. You say you are "not able to understand why we can use that theorem." **Why?** Which of the assumptions are you unclear about in order to apply the theorem?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I gave the wrong $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is absolutely integrable on some finite interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Then one form of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma states that
$$
          \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\sin(rt+\phi)dt =0, \;\;\;\forall \phi\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

You can use this version to get what you want. The above holds for $\sin$ if $\phi=0$ and it holds for $\cos$ if $\phi=-\pi/2$. Then $2\pi(N+1)$ becomes $r$.